# WCF - How to use a custom System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite with a custom binding

Tags: c#, security, wcf

Due to specific security requirements, no default [SecurityAlgorithmSuite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.security.securityalgorithmsuite?view=netframework-4.8) fits my need. I need the [Basic256Sha256](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.security.securityalgorithmsuite.basic256sha256?view=netframework-4.8#System_ServiceModel_Security_SecurityAlgorithmSuite_Basic256Sha256) suite, with just changing the DefaultAsymmetricSignatureAlgorithm to RsaSha1Signature.

To achieve this, I made a custom SecurityAlgorithmSuite according to [this msdn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/specifying-a-custom-crypto-algorithm). However, I can find no way to actually use it with a custom binding I made and need to use via a configuration file.

I can make an instance of the custom binding and assign the custom security algorithm suite as follows:

```
MyCustomHttpBinding binding = new MyCustomHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = new MyCustomAlgorithmSuite();
```

However I can't do this while using wcf service and configuration file. I need to do this either in the custom binding or in the configuration file.

The only way to define a security algorithm suite in the custom binding I found is here:

```
AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement sbe = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(                MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10, true);
sbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256;
```

but I can only used the default, predefined ones.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try to configure it through code.You can refer to this link for details:https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2265